# Proof of necessary condition of injection without strict monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

According to the proof details in [Continuous Injection of Interval is Strictly Monotone](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Injection_of_Interval_is_Strictly_Monotone),  I deduce a statement:

**Statement:**  if an injective  function $f \colon D\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$  is not strictly monotone, then
 there exist  $x,y,z∈D$  with $ x<y<z$ such that either $f(x)<f(y)$ and $f(y)>f(z),$  or $f(x)>f(y)$ and $f(y)<f(z).$

But I have trouble in proving this **statement**, or even disprove it.  My trial is following.

Suppose  otherwise the conclusion of the **statement** is not true, then we have 
\begin{align*}
\forall x, y, z\in D:  x<y<z \implies (f(x)>f(y) \lor f(y)<f(z)) \land (f(x)<f(y)\lor f(y)>f(z)).
\end{align*}
Because 
\begin{align*}
&(f(x)>f(y) \lor f(y)<f(z)) \land (f(x)<f(y)\lor f(y)>f(z))\\
\iff&(f(x)>f(y)\land f(x)<f(y))\lor (f(x)>f(y)\land f(y)>f(z))\lor (f(y)<f(z)\land f(x)<f(y))\lor (f(y)<f(z)\land f(y)>f(z))\\
\iff &(f(x)>f(z))\lor (f(z)>f(x)),
\end{align*}
and for  all statements $P, Q, R,$
\begin{gather*}
P\implies (Q\lor R) \text{ is logically equivalent to }  (P\implies Q) \lor (P\implies R),
\end{gather*}
we have 
$$\forall x, y, z\in D:  x<y<z \implies (f(x)>f(y) \lor f(y)<f(z)) \land (f(x)<f(y)\lor f(y)>f(z))$$ is logically equivalent to 
\begin{gather*}
\forall x,z\in D: (x<z\implies f(x)>f(z)) \lor (x<z\implies f(x)<f(z)).
\end{gather*}
But we know that the statement 
$$\forall x,z\in D: (x<z\implies f(x)>f(z)) \lor (x<z\implies f(x)<f(z))$$ is not equivalent to \begin{gather*}\tag{$\star$}(\forall x,z\in D: x<z\implies f(x)>f(z)) \lor (\forall x,z\in D: x<z\implies f(x)<f(z))!\end{gather*}
As you can see, $(\star)$ is the definition that $f$ is strictly increasing, or strictly decreasing on $D.$ 
Thus I was stuck!

But if the domain $D$  of definition of $f$ is an interval, and $f$ is continuous on $D,$ I have proved that the **statement** is true. Thus I guess that maybe the continuity and connectedness conditions are redundant for this **statement**.

So, if you think that the **statement** is true, how to prove it. If it is false, can you construct a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is not strictly decreasing, there are some $a, b \in D$, such that $a < b$ and $f(a) \leq f(b)$. Since $f$ is injective, $f(a) < f(b)$. Since $f$ is not strictly increasing, there are some $c, d \in D$, such that $c < d$ and $f(c) \geq f(d)$. Since $f$ is injective, $f(c) > f(d)$.

Case 1: $a < b < c < d$. If $f(b) < f(c)$, set $(x,y,z) := (b,c,d)$. Otherwise, set $(x,y,z) := (a,b,c)$.

Case 2: $a < b = c < d$. Set $(x,y,z) := (a,b,c)$.

Case 3: $a < c < b < d$. If $f(a) < f(c)$, set $(x,y,z):=(a,c,d)$. Otherwise, set $(x,y,z):=(a,c,b)$.

Case 4: $a < c < b = d$. Set $(x,y,z):=(a,c,b)$.

Case 5: $a < c < d < b$. If $f(a) < f(c)$, set $(x,y,z):=(a,c,d)$. Otherwise, set $(x,y,z):=(a,c,b)$.

Case 6: $a = c < b < d$. Set $(x,y,z):=(a,b,d)$.

Case 7: $a=c < b = d$. Impossible!

Case 8: $a=c < d < b$. Set $(x,y,z):=(a,d,b)$.

Case 9: $c < a < b < d$. If $f(c) < f(a)$, set $(x,y,z):=(c,a,d)$. Otherwise, set $(x,y,z):=(c,a,b)$.

Case 10: $c < a < b = d$. Set $(x,y,z):=(c,a,b)$.

Case 11: $c < a < d < b$. If $f(c) < f(a)$, set $(x,y,z):=(c,a,d)$. Otherwise, set $(x,y,z):=(c,a,b)$.

Case 12: $c < a = d < b$. Set $(x,y,z):=(c,a,b)$.

Case 13: $c < d < a < b$. If $f(d) < f(a)$, set $(x,y,z):=(c,d,a)$. Otherwise, set $(x,y,z):=(d,a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've got it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple proof that avoids all those mind-numbing cases!

*Lemma:* Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}.$ If $g\colon D\to\mathbb{R}$ is strictly monotonic on every 3-element subset of $D,$ then $g$ is strictly monotonic on every subset of $D$ of cardinality $\le4.$

*Proof of Lemma:* It's sufficient to prove the conclusion for subsets of cardinality exactly $4,$ since it's trivially true for sets of size $3$ or less. So let $a \lt b \lt c\lt d$ be elements of $D.$ Then $g$ is strictly monotonic on both $\lbrace a, b, c \rbrace$ and $\lbrace b, c, d \rbrace.$  In fact, if $g(b)\lt g(c),$ then $g$ is strictly increasing on both those $3-$element sets; and if $g(b)\gt g(c),$ then $g$ is strictly decreasing on both those $3-$element sets.  It follows that $g$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on the $4$-element set $\lbrace a, b, c,d \rbrace.$
$$ $$
The problem now follows immediately: Assume $f$ is injective and not strictly monotonic. Then:

$\bullet$ There exist $a$ and $b$ such that $a\lt b$ and $f(a) \gt f(b)$ (since $f$ isn't strictly increasing).

$\bullet$ There exist $c$ and $d$ such that $c\lt d$ and $f(c) \lt f(d)$ (since $f$ isn't strictly decreasing).

But now $\lbrace a, b, c, d \rbrace$ is a subset of $D$ of cardinality at most $4$ on which $f$ isn't strictly monotonic. So, applying the lemma, there's some $3$-element subset of $D$ on which $f$ is not strictly monotonic, which is exactly what we need to prove.